# How do I know whether my display driver supports DirectX or not?

Tags: directx, directx-9, directx-10, directx-11

[image]I would like to know whether my display driver supports DirectX 11 or not? How do I know the display drivers's capability? Especially, how do I know whether it is supporting shading language or not?

Answer (score 1):

Start > Run... and type

```
dxdiag
```

For my case (see attached screenshot), I can run all DirectDraw Tests, but my card doesn't support Direct3D (it is grayed out).
If you need more details on the card support, then maybe other tools will help (I don't know which one though)[image]

Comment: I run this, found I have DirectX, but how can I be sure my display drivers support all its feature or not?

Comment: On the "Display" Tab it will let you run some DirectX tests, and it will show what options are supported.

Comment: I did not find "run some DirectX tests" on the display tab. It only shows DirectDraw Acceleration, Direct3D Acceleration, AGP Texture Acceleration is enabled

Comment: Right, "Test Direct3D" and "Test DirectDraw". Did you try them and see the results? It will diagnose the card/driver support. Anything that allows you to "Enable" or "Disable" is supported, the rest isn't.

Comment: why you have more setting than me?

Comment: I am using Windows XP, yours look like Vista or Windows 7. Anyway, from the kind of details you need (HLSL and probably other things) I don't think this DxDiag tool will help. Maybe better luck with the other answer

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to check that from user's point of view - check your video card's manufacturer website, or look at the package your card was in :) For example, nVidia cards that are based on 200-series chip, supports DirectX 10, 400- and 500-series supports DirectX 11.

If you mean from the code - D3D11CreateDevice returns that information as featureLevel - check DirectX SDK for details.

All DirectX 10-compliant cards support Shader Model 4.0 (so vs_4_0, ps_4_0, gs_4_0, and optionally cs_4_0), DirectX 10.1-compatible - Shader Model 4.1(so vs_4_1, ps_4_1, gs_4_1, and optionally cs_4_x), DirectX 11-compatible - Shader Model 5.0(so vs_5_0, ps_5_0, gs_5_0, cs_5_0, hs_5_0, ds_5_0).

UPDATE:
Check this out: http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/intel915g/sb/cs-011807.htm Looks like your card is DirectX 10-compliant.